# Is there a "terraform" or "meta" terraform provider?

Tags: terraform

Is there a provider available that can manage terraform roots? Some sort of orchestration to map multiple roots / deployment components together?

For example, if i wanted to create a distributed platform in AWS, I might want to create a root for core / network that provisions VPC, subnets, routing etc. Then another root that provisions kubernetes. A number of microservices running in ec2/asg /  kubernetes / lambda / etc may have their own roots too. For regular deployments of microservices, individual roots can then be used to deploy updates to the service, but if i wanted to provision the entire platform, is there a provider that could apply multiple roots with dependencies?

The code might look something like:

```
resource "terraform_root" "core" {
  root_location: core/network
}

resource "terraform_root" "kubernetes" {
    depends: [terraform_root.core]
    root_location: git@github.com:myorg/myrepo?ver=1.2.1
    variables : { something }
}

resource "terraform_root" "microservice_x" {
    depends: [terraform_root.kubernetes]
    root_location: some_location
}
```

if there isnt one, would creating a custom provider like this be some sort of anti-pattern with tf? what would the concerns be?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/), a wrapper for Terraform that allows you to create dependencies between modules and minimize repetitive code. With Terragrunt, you can execute multiple modules at once but still keep the state separated. You can also execute hooks before and after Terraform runs, and you can easily work with multiple AWS accounts. See [this repo](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

The intended way to model this with Terraform is to [use Terraform modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html), which allow you manage several collections of resources at once while keeping them namespaced from one another.

Having a Terraform provider that runs a child instance of Terraform would *mostly* just be a more complex version of using Terraform modules. It would have one significant distinct behavior, though: each of these "configuration roots" would have its own backend and thus its own set of states (per workspace). While it is often recommended to split your Terraform-managed infrastructure into several states, the rationale for doing so is that you can then `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` them separately, to manage risk of unintended impacts of broad changes across an entire stack. Having the many separate "configuration roots" be managed by a single run of `terraform apply` would seem to defeat that advantage, and thus just reduce back to the effect of modules in a single configuration.

For situations where you *have* decomposed your system into multiple separate Terraform configurations, [the provider named `terraform`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/index.html) can retrieve the outputs from the state of one configuration to use in another, access-control permitting. So in that sense there *is* a "meta Terraform provider", but not in the sense you intended.

---

Putting aside the value of doing such a thing, it does seem like it would be *technically possible* to implement a Terraform provider that wraps Terraform, as follows:

- When the provider is asked to create a plan, run `terraform plan -out=tempfile` and then `terraform show -json tempfile` to obtain a machine-readable version of the plan and merge that into the provider's plan response somehow. That would presumably end up showing the planned resource changes as changes to attributes on the single resource that is representing the whole child configuration, maybe like this:

  ```
   ~ resource "terraform_config" "example" {
     ~ resources = {
         ~ "aws_instance.example[0]" = {
               ami           = "ami-abc123"
             ~ instance_type = "t2.micro" -> "m3.medium"
           }
         ~ "aws_instance.example[1]" = {
               ami           = "ami-abc123"
             ~ instance_type = "t2.micro" -> "m3.medium"
           }
       }
       root_dir  = "./child_thingy"
       variables = {
         example = "baz"
       }
   }
  ```
- When the provider is asked to apply the change, run `terraform apply tempfile` to apply the change. To do that robustly, I suppose it would need to embed the saved binary plan file from the inner `terraform plan` in the outer `terraform plan` result, so it can be sure to be applying the correct plan.

The above does show at least one visible difference of this model vs. the built-in idea of Terraform modules: all of the changes for the other configurations would be seen by the outer Terraform as updates to a single resource each, whereas with modules Terraform would show all of the changes at the top level.

Another complexity to deal with here is what to do with changes in a nested configuration that require resource replacement. Terraform currently has no way for a provider to signal that one nested part of the object needs to be "replaced", so the provider would either need to model it as destroy and then re-creating the entire configuration or present it as an update but then silently replace the object internally anyway. Neither of those sound acceptable for everyday use.

Comment: Thanks Martin, informative response. So yes - the reason for a number of roots is definitely for what you described, commonly referred to as reducing blast radius. And regular day to day infrastructure management would involve doing an apply is specific roots where changes are needed. We're also using the terraform provider's remote state data object to pass dependancy information between roots (e.g. subnet IDs from core to service deployment roots).  To echo the use-cases that this was raised for: DR or re-provisioning of a full platform ecosystem (e.g. creating a new environment)

Comment: "If I wanted to recreate a full service oriented platform defined in TF roots in an automated manner, is there a native TF provider that can help me do this?" is possibly a way of phrasing the question better. Non-TF alternatives would include  CI pipeline or a bash script